# React change content based on item selected in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I have three different JSXs in the Component folder and each of them represents a different table.
The function names inside these JSXs are:

- Table1
- Table2
- Table3

The goal for this website is to switch to different table functions(`<Table1 />,<Table2 />, <Table3 />`) according to the selection in the dropdown.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Table1 from './component/table.jsx';
import Table2 from './component/table2.jsx';
import Table3 from './component/table3.jsx';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

function App() {
  
  const [value,setValue]=useState('');
  const handleSelect=(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
    setValue(e)
  }
  function Tab(value) {
  
    if (value.toString() == 'Table2') {
      return <Table2 />;
    }else if (value.toString()=='Table1') {
      return <Table1 />;
    }else {
      return <Table3 />;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <Dropdown  onSelect={handleSelect}>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
          Dropdown Button
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="Table1">1</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="Table2">2</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="Table3">3</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      <h4>You selected {value}</h4>
      <Tab value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

[Please check animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bfsU.gif)

As you can see, currently the dropdown does go to the correct string, but unfortunately, in function Tab(value), this always returns  no matter what I chose.

Please kindly advise what I should modify in function Tab(value) to make it work.

Comment: `function Tab(value) {` needs to be `function Tab({ value }) {` (it's *a* prop, not all props)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `Tab` outside of your `App` component and in props you must use `{}` to destrure the props to get value:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Table1 from './component/table.jsx';
import Table2 from './component/table2.jsx';
import Table3 from './component/table3.jsx';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

function App() {
  
  const [value,setValue]=useState('');
  const handleSelect=(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
    setValue(e)
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <Dropdown  onSelect={handleSelect}>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
          Dropdown Button
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="Table1">1</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="Table2">2</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="Table3">3</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      <h4>You selected {value}</h4>
      <Tab value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Tab({value}) {
  
    if (value.toString() == 'Table2') {
      return <Table2 />;
    }else if (value.toString()=='Table1') {
      return <Table1 />;
    }else {
      return <Table3 />;
    }
  }

export default App;
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to typo-type questions.

Comment: You are a legend, mate! Will accept the answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't vote for you due to my low reputation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is:** You are getting an `object` inside your `function parameters` and you are comparing that `object` with `Table 2` and `Table 1`.

So just change your function to this:

```
function Tab(e) {
    if (e.value === 'Table2') {
      return <Table2 />;
    } else if (e.value === 'Table1') {
      return <Table1 />;
    } else {
      return <Table3 />;
    }
 }
```

**Advice:**

1. *Use === instead of == (Unrelated to answer)*
2. *No need to use toString as your all DropDown values have string values*

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Btw Upvote helps us more than Thanks 